# Como enviar formulário sem refresh da página?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Queria saber como que eu envio formulário sem refresh, eu consegui colocar para não dar refresh mas eu quero que apareça uma tela logo após dar o submit tipo "E-mail enviado com sucesso".

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 


$('#forms').on('submit', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'dados.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#forms').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

$(".menu").show('fast');
$('#atuar').show('fast');        }

    });

    return false;

});
});
</script>
<style>

    .menu{

position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        background: #12C12B;
    }   
    #atuar{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
        background: red;

    }

</style>
<body>
<div>
<form id="forms">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="digite o nome" />
<input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
</div>

<div class="menu" hidden>enviado com sucesso!</div>
<div id="atuar" hidden ><input type="button" value="download"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

agora a pagina que recebe os dados
dados.php

```
<?php

$dados = $_POST['name'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer dessa forma utilizando jquery e ajax:

```
<p></p>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var json = '{"mensagem":[{' +
               '"assunto":"' + tIdP + '",' +
               '}]}';
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'file.php',
      data: {'json': json},
      success: function (data) {
        $('p').append('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```